# Handling Versioning of a file using URL manager in yii 1.x

Tags: yii

I need to handle version of a file on my website. I am working on yii 1.
I have created APIs in one of the controller. I need to create a support for old version as well as new version.

So I was thinking if I use file names like Web1_1Controller.php for version 1.1 and so on. 
Its url would be like `http://<domainname.com>/Web/<action>?ver=1.1&type=<sometype>&id=<someid>&limit=10&offset......` could have many variables.

Also can this be managed using url manager?

More example:

```
http://domain.com/Web/login?api=7677&a_ver=1.1 should point to Web1.1Controller or Web1_1Controller
http://domain.com/Web/login?api=7677&a_ver=1.2 should point to Web1.2Controller or Web1_2Controller
```

I am wondering to use a separate controller file for each version and not sure how to achieve it, But it should only be implemented with 'Web' Controller and all the rest should work as they are working now. Can I achieve this using URL manager? Or any other idea?

Edit:

Few Web services are used to upload user images uploaded via android /iphone devices which are posting image.

I am using code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['qqfile']['name'])){

    ob_start();
    echo $ajax_controller->actionUploadImage($userId);
    $data=ob_get_clean();
    $data_arr=json_decode($data,true);

    }
```

ActionUploadImage is again using `Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");` this plugin to upload file.

If I redirect file @scaisEdge won't it create issue in uploading images?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solustion i think is using redirect inside you api controller

```
$this->redirect(<controller>/<action>)
```

you can redirect you controller action in the way you prefer..

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail

Comment: I think about it as well but I have to upload files in few web services and it won't work that way.